# Find and extract repeated occurrences of a string in text including tags

Tags: php, string, substring

Suppose I have this piece of text:

```
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog
The quick brown fox jumps over the <b>lazy dog</b>
The quick brown fox <b>jumps over</b> the lazy dog
```

I want to get and extract all occurrences of this string from the text above:

```
<b>quick brown</b>
<b>lazy dog</b>
<b>jumps over</b>
```

Now I know I would need a while loop that checks until the end of the text and some string functions, but I'm not sure which ones.

Appreciate if someone could help with this.

Comment: You can use regular expressions or maybe some substring (substr php command).

Comment: @user481913, finally updated my answer one more time, to full comply with your question!

Comment: Edit - The text between the <b> and </b> is not always the same... Changed the question above to reflect this.  I'm trying out various the solutions  offered to see which one fits the best...

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev - Thank You, I'd try it out...

Comment: @user481913 You're welcome! Tell me if you need more help!

Comment: @user481913 I have just extended the functionality and flexibility of my code, so you could use it with multiple HTML tags! Take a look at `EDIT 1` and see how it works!

Answer (score 0):

Do like this..

```
<?php
$html='The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog';

function funcx($v)
{
    return "<b>".$v."</b>";
}

preg_match_all('~<b>(.*?)<\/b>~', $html, $matches);
$results=array_map('funcx',$matches[1]);
var_dump($results);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '<b>quick brown</b>' (length=18)
  1 => string '<b>quick brown</b>' (length=18)
  2 => string '<b>quick brown</b>' (length=18)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would want to use regex, try the following:

```
/<b ?.*>(.*)<\/b>/
```

It will catch everything inside `<b></b>` tags including tags themselves.

[Online Example](http://regex101.com/r/yJ3nQ5)

You could expand the usage of the regex above to more than only one `<b>` tag by using simple function and pass a tag you would want to catch:

*Example:*

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagname)
{
    $pattern = '/<'.$tagname.'>.*?<\/'.$tagname.'>/is';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
    return $matches;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
$string = 'The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog \
           The <b>quick black</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog \
           The <b>quick white</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$text = getTextBetweenTags($string, "b");
print_r($text);
```

*Output:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <b>quick brown</b>
            [1] => <b>quick black</b>
            [2] => <b>quick white</b>
        )

)
```

[Online Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/i848Ci)

#### EDIT 1:

I have extended the function above for you, so it will work with multiple tags:

*Example:*

```
function getTextBetweenTags($string, $tagsname)
{
    $tagsname = explode(',',$tagsname);
    foreach ($tagsname as $tagname) 
    {
        $pattern = '/<'.$tagname.'>.*?<\/'.$tagname.'>/is';
        preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
        $results[] = $matches;
    }
    return $results;
}
```

*Usage:*

```
$string = 'The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps <strong>over</strong> the lazy dog \
           The <b>quick black</b> fox jumps over the <span>lazy</span> dog \
           The <b>quick white</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$text = getTextBetweenTags($string, "b,strong,span"); // Single or multiple HTML tags
print_r($text);
```

*Output:*

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <b>quick brown</b>
                    [1] => <b>quick black</b>
                    [2] => <b>quick white</b>
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <strong>over</strong>
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => <span>lazy</span>
                )

        )

)
```

[Online Example](http://ideone.com/XR5kPl)

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = "The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog
The <b>quick brown</b> fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$part = "<b>quick brown</b>";
$count = substr_count($text, $part);
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
{
echo $part."<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

quick brown

quick brown

quick brown

If you replace

`echo $part."<br>";`

with

`echo htmlspecialchars($part)."<br>";`

**OUTPUT**

```
<b>quick brown</b>
<b>quick brown</b>
<b>quick brown</b>
```

Comment: This is the same answer that I already posted, you just need more code in your solution.